# httpContext.Session lost value

Tags: c#, session, session-state

i have a web site, which sometimes the Session lost the value.
Here is what i do:
In the Login ActionResult, in the Controller:

```
private ActionResult Login(string user, string pass){
   if (Membership.ValidateUser(user, pass))
   {
      Response.Cookies.Clear();
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, true);
      System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"] = user;
      return Json(new {success = true});
   }
 }
```

Here, the session set fine. 
But then, in the override AuthorizeAttribute class:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
   var user = HttpContext.Current.User;
   if (user == null) return false;
   if (httpContext.Session?["userName"] == null) return false;
   try
   {
      if (user.IsInRole("Admin")) return true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Here the session is NULL.
I found a pattern which happens:

1. Open chrome
2. Enter to the site, and login --> Works fine
3. Close chrome
4. Open chrome again
5. Enter to the site and login --> Here lose the session, and i can`t login

Then, if i logout (http://site/logout), then, i can login again fine. And here is the logout action:

```
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {;
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = null;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mati...so, when you try to log in again, what happens(an error or you can't login again until you destroy the session?)

Comment: It redirects to the login page again.

Comment: Startup.Auth
dig this a little.. 

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions

I think it is related to cookie

Comment: You can also try changing the workflow of your application...so, if an user logs in, it shouldn't exist a session for that user, right....so in your `Login` method you can check if the session exist, and if the session exist, destroy it, like: `if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["company_path"]!= null){  //Destroy session code  }`

Comment: But in the Login action, i have to create the session, not destroy it..

Comment: Yeah but if exist already then destroy it...basically when you close the browser, your session still exist server side....but the cookie on the client don't...in order to have a clean login you need to do that